# After updating answers in a SCORM lesson in the same attempt, the score result doesn't update - MOODLE

Tags: php, moodle, scorm

After adding a SCORM lesson in MOODLE, I took an attempt and then the SCORM lesson gives me a score result. Then, I took the same attempt again(Not "Enter a new attempt"), answer all the quizzes, the score result doesn't change. No matter how much time I take the same attempt and update quizzes' answers, the score result stays the same.

Is this how SCORM lessons behave or the SCORM package I am using has any bug?

Comment: So what happens if you do a new attempt?  Does that work?  If yes then it's probably not a scorm package bug but just how scorm works on Moodle.  Also, which Moodle version?

Comment: @brianlmerritt if I do a new attempt, then I get a proper score result. so, I think SCORM works this way?

Comment: A lot depends on Moodle version and SCORM settings, plus of course what package created the SCORM lesson in the first place and what SCORM version and settings were made when publishing it.